# Sql Server 2014 Express Edition database backup from c# - Sql Error

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am using Sql Server 2014 Express Edition.  I am using Visual Studio 2015.
I have created a c# Winform app that uses a database.  In the app, I have a button that is suppose to backup the database.   On the button click event, the sql command

```
"backup database testdb to disk = @fullfilename";
```

is executed using sqlcommand and ExecuteNonQuery.

When I test this out, I get an error:

> Failed to backup databaseSystem.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
>   (0x80131904) Operating system error 3(The system cannot find the path
>   specified).

I am testing the backup trying to get it to save to a mapped drive.  I have looked on google and tried the approached recommended.  I have change the login service for Sql Server to a domain user.  I have mapped the drive using that same domain user's credentials.  I have verified that the user has all permissions to the share,etc.  No joy.  Same problem.

Would love to hear some pointers on how to get this to work.  Note:  it works just fine if you use a local, non mapped drive.

Note:  It must use mapped drives or UNC's.  Its a requirement.

thanks.

Comment: Doesn't it work with UNC too or only with mapped drive?

Comment: Does the proc/query run in SQL separate from your C# app?

Comment: I would definitely suggest providing the value of @fullfilename. I'm guessing we may have a double-slashing (escaping) issue or something fairly basic at hand, Also, are you certain the drive you are using is actually mapped at the time the command is executed? This would be a point at which I'd encourage the use of UNC paths over drive letters...

Answer (score 0):

Backup to UNC is supported and should work without problems.

My troubleshooting suggestions:

1. Use UNC instead of mapped drive and make sure the destination folder exists prior to starting the backup
2. Copy the SQL command into SSMS and manually start the backup
3. If backup via SSMS works and your app still fails, startup SQL Profiler and look at the SQL command your app sends

Good luck!

Comment: Well, I guess I got a case of the stupids.  After some wrangling, found that UNC's were working just fine.  Mapped drives were a no go.